# How can I get all Word "objects" in a Word document using Interop / VSTO?

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, office-interop, aspose.words

In Aspose, you can do `document.GetChildNodes(NodeType.Any, true)` to get all the "nodes" in the document.

Is there such a functionality for VSTO / Interop?

I know there are ways to get all ContentControls or all Tables or whatnot, but I'd like to get all objects in the order they appear in the document and not just 1 type of object.

Comment: What particular objects are you interested in? Or in other Word, what kind of things do you mean with *objects*? It also will help getting a good answer if you explain what you plan to do with these objects once you retrieved them.

Comment: I'd like to get their positioning in the document, and potentially, other info. For example, a Table Of Contents has hyperlinks but what type of objects are those hyperlinks linked to?